# Is it pythonic to use shortcut expression instead of ternary?

Tags: python, pep8

I often use the ternary operator in python and it works great :-)
Now i've seen that it would be possible to use the 'or' operator for most of that cases.
For example:

```py
# Ternary operator example
class Foo:
    first = 'First'
    second = 'Second'
    def bar(self):
        return self.first if self.first else self.second


foo=Foo()
foo.bar()  # returns 'First'

foo.first = None
foo.bar()  # returns 'Second'
```

The same functionality could be achieved using the 'or'-operator as a [Short-cirquit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

```py
# Short-cirquit evaluation
class Foo:
    first = 'First'
    second = 'Second'
    def bar(self):
        return self.first or self.second


foo=Foo()
foo.bar()  # returns 'First'

foo.first = None
foo.bar()  # returns 'Second'
```

Now the question:

Would the usage of the Short-cirquit evaluation be considered as pep-8 and pythonic usage or is it not explicit enough? 
Is it accepted as a professional solution?

Comment: Never knew that would work. Personally, I'll start using this whenever I can :')

Comment: I would say that `a if a else b` and `a or b` are equivalent, except when evaluating `a` has a side effect. Barring that, `or` should be fine, but I could see this being a matter of opinion.

Comment: `a and b or c` in place of `b if a else c` is what you want to avoid. (Indeed, the conditional expression was introduced *because* `a and b or c` is different when `b` can be false.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly reasonable to use short-circuit with either `or` or `and`.  The important part is that the resulting code should be the most readable and maintainable version you can make.  For instance, when I crawl down a list of `get` references, I'll do something like

```
return obj and obj.record and obj.record.field_I_want
```

This does a nice job of giving me `None` when anything in the reference sequence doesn't exist, but returns the field value if everything is healthy.

Comment: That assumes that `obj.record` cannot both be "falsey" *and* have the desired attribute.

Comment: @chepner if you look at the things that evaluate falsey, you'll find it's highly unlikely they'd have an attribute. It should be noted that before the ternary operator was added to Python, this was the accepted way of doing things; it would be changing history to declare it un-Pythonic now.

Comment: @chepner You could also write `obj.record != some_value` in the expression if needed.

Comment: @Prune If something in your example doesn't exist, it will raise an `AttributeError` at some point, not short-circuit the `and` operator. Did you mean something like `obj and getattr(obj, 'record') and getattr(obj.record, 'field_I_want')`?

Comment: +1 from me for "most readable and maintainable". In this case, I think it falls under "Explicit is better than implicit"

Comment: `try: return obj.record.field_I_want except AttributeError: return None` would probably be cleaner in that case.