# or as a shortcut for if ... is not None else

Tags: python

Very often I will have assignments like:

```
data = {
    'a': var_a if var_a is not None else default_a,
    ...
}
```

This is somewhat verbose. I think this can be shortened to

```
data = {
    'a': var_a or default_a,
    ...
}
```

at least if I know that `var_a` will not take on a value like 0 or [].

Are there any downsides to using this shorter notation?

Comment: If ```var_a``` is ```False```, ```None``` will be assigned i guess ? Maybe it will be the same with 0 ?

Comment: It cannot be shortened like that. `var_a or default_a` simply assigns a boolean that is `True` if either of the two inputs are True.

Comment: @xdurch0 $ python3 -c "print(None or 'abc')" -- output: abc

Comment: @xdurch0, ...no, it doesn't. Try that in a repl.

Comment: @cheersmate, the big downside is the difference between testing identity as None vs testing truthiness. They're semantically different, and if you actually wanted a truthiness test, I'd argue that `is None` was wrong in the original code; whereas if the only _desired_ semantic is replacing the specific value `None`, the new code has additional undesired behavior, and those are from whence bugs are born. But if you genuinely don't care about that difference, then you're fine.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right. But if that's the only caveat, I might be willing to go with it. Or at least use it in cases where the truthiness test makes sense.

Comment: Once upon a time, you *had* to write `var_a or default_a`, then figure out what exceptions made it fail and work around them. `... if ... else ...` was added to the language to *address* that. You're going in the wrong direction :)

Comment: Right. I'm not going to add an answer endorsing that approach, because I believe in rigor in design and being careful about corner cases. But there aren't more dangers hiding that you aren't aware of.

Comment: I don't like it because you're going from explicit to a language specific implicit. Just use a helper function if you want to reuse that if block a lot.

Comment: @CJR, functions in Python can't short-circuit evaluation of their arguments unless you do something like make the conditionally evaluated part a separate function passed as a lambda, and that's a lot of overhead.

Comment: If [PEP-505](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/) ever gets approved, you'll be able to write `var_a ?? default_a`. (Don't hold your breath, though.) See https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-505-status/4612/10 for some insight as to why the proposal is deferred, rather than having been rejected.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's true but also irrelevant for this problem, which only uses the short circuit in the thing I don't like and recommend not using.

Comment: Two highly related questions are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808543/is-it-pythonic-to-use-shortcut-expression-instead-of-ternary and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59874770/should-i-compare-with-none-explicitly

Comment: @CJR, pardon? _Both_ `if foo is None then bar else foo` and `foo or bar` only evaluate `bar` in the event that `foo`'s result requires it. Thus, they're effectively _both_ short-circuiting. Whereas if you call a function -- say, `one_of(foo, bar)` -- they're both evaluated as part of the function call itself.

Comment: Oh good, in the quest to be technically correct, not executing else blocks is now short circuiting. Excuse me, I'm going to short circuit a script I wrote by not executing it.

Comment: Heh. I may have overstretched some terminology, but using an argument about terminology to respond to an objection about performance and side effects is also maybe a stretch.

Comment: Fair enough. I will call this internet argument an internet draw. (You are right about the function overhead but it's hard for me to care about that kinda cost for python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var_a or default_a` is the usual way to do it when None is treated the same as any 'Falsy' values (0, [], False, ...).

If you specifically need to check for None, you could express it like this:

```
'a': (var_a,default_a)[var_a is None]
```

or at least avoid the `not` by reversing the order

```
'a': default_a if var_a is None else var_a
```

If you're going to do this often, you could make a function to shorten the expression:

```
def noNone(v,d): d if v is None else v
```

...

```
'a': noNone(var_a,default_a)
```

Comment: The specific problem is that there are lots of falsey values that *aren't* `None`, which is where `var_a or default_a` breaks (or at least is not equivalent). The workaround you suggest just added the overhead of calling a function with no great increase in readability.

Answer (score 3):

Bad if `var_a` is [falsy](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html). This includes the boolean False, zero of any numeric type and a few others. For example, `[] or 'foo'` prints 'foo'. I like the idea, maybe there is some other Pythonian way to make it work.